# How to view pdf without downloading?

Tags: php, pdf, view, download

Good day everyone I am using a select command to view pdf from database it is working but it tries to download all pdf every time the page is refresh. I want it to be a normal list then download once click.

here is my code

```
<?php
function selectFishprice()
{
    try {
        $connection = connect();
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT price AS pdf_path, Date FROM upload WHERE id = 1";
        $statement = $connection->query($sqlQuery);
        $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $Fishprices = $statement->fetchAll();
        if (!empty($Fishprices)) {
            return $Fishprices;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $exception) {
        die("Error: " . $exception->getMessage());
    }
}

$fishPrices = selectFishprice();
?>
<table id="users">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Fish Market Price</th>
            <th scope="col">As of</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
    if (!empty($fishPrices)) {
        foreach ($fishPrices as $fishPrice) {
            $date = strtotime($fishPrice['Date']);
?>
            <tr class="table-primary">
            <td scope="row"><img src="<?= $fishPrice['pdf_path'] ?>"/></td>
            <td scope="row"><?= date('M j Y', $date)?></td>
            <?php
        }
    } else {
?>
        <tr class="table-primary">
            <td class="text-center" colspan="4" scope="row">No records found.</td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I read from the site to use "header" but I don't understand where do I put the "header"? Any help is appreciated thank you

Comment: You show absolutely no code that has anything to do with a PDF.

Comment: Hello. $fishPrice['price'] contains the pdf path  "price" is just the name of the field in the table.

Comment: Then why are you using the path to a PDF file as the src of an `img` element? And how would this try to “download” anything?

Comment: Because I thought it would be similar to other list that I made, anyways I replace the img element with embed kinda works now. Thank you for pointing that.

Comment: Would you like to show a download link or to embed a PDF in your page? It's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`anchor tag (i.e. <a>)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

```
function selectFishprice()
{
    try {
        $connection = connect();
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $statement = $connection->query("SELECT price, Date FROM upload WHERE id = 1 ");
        $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $Fishprices = $statement->fetchAll();
        if (!empty($Fishprices)) {
            return $Fishprices;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $exception) {
        die("Error: " . $exception->getMessage());
    }
}

$fishPrices = selectFishprice();

         <table id="users">
               <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Fish Market Price</th>
                       <th scope="col">As of</th>
                        </thead>
                         <tbody>
                         <?php
                          if(!empty($fishPrices)) {
                             foreach ($fishPrices as $fishPrice) {
                                 $date = strtotime($fishPrice['Date']);
                              ?>
                             <tr class="table-primary">
                            <td scope="row"><a href ="<?= $fishPrice['price'] ?>" target="_blank"><img src="" alt="PDF"/></a></td>
                             <td scope="row"><?= date('M j Y', $date)?></td>
                             <?php
                             }
                           } else {
                             ?>
                           <tr class="table-primary">
                            <td class="text-center" colspan="4" scope="row">No records found.</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

Comment: Thank you. I already replace the embed tag with the anchor tag before upon realizing that it should not be treated like an image.